# Selecting multiple taxonomy terms in blog Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I've just started learning Drupal 7 and while I was creating a blog I wanted to give it a relation but it must be related to multiple articles through taxonomy terms.

In the *Blog* content type, I created a *relation* field, set the Field Type to *Term Reference* and Widget to *Check boxes/radio buttons*.

Here is a snapshot http://varunsharmak2.com/blog-content-type.png

Now when I create a blog entry, it shows all the Taxonomy terms as radio buttons in Relation section.

Here is a snapshot of it. [http://varunsharmak2.com/relation.png](http://varunsharmak2.com/screenshot-localhost-2018-05-11-11-28-26.png)

I want checkboxes in place of radio buttons.

How can I get check boxes?

Answer (score 1):

When you edit that field there should be an option to select how many tags can be selected? Default is one, but you can select 2,3... and finally unlimited. That field is drop-down field. Select unlimited.

Your second screenshot is not working btw.